# Limit of a function with 2 variables (including absolute values)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can someone give me a hint of how we calculate this limit (if it exists)?

$\displaystyle \large \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\left|x\right|^{e^{1/|x|}}y}{x-y} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limit exists if there exists $L$ such that for every $a_n$ and $b_n$, it can be proved if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0, \forall n (a_n\not =0)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0,\forall n(b_n\not = 0)$, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|a_n|^{e^{\frac{1}{a_n}}}b_n}{a_n-b_n}=L$$
If we choose $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, because $a_n-b_n=0$, there for the above limit is not definable, so this limit does not exist.